# Eclipse won't recognize my android phone -> Can't debug

Tags: android, macos, adb, eclipse-adt

All of a sudden Eclipse stopped recognizing my android device. So when I hit the Play-Button I get the following message:

> No compatible targets were found. Do you wish to add a new Android
>   Virtual Device?

Strangely on my device it says that USB-Debugging is connected, as soon as I plug it into my macbook.

What could be the problem here?
Thanks!

PS: I'm using a Samsung Galaxy i5800 and a MacbookPro.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should check if your adb daemon is run (I assume you have android sdk installed). Please try taping this in terminal:

```
adb devices
```

And if there is nothing after `List of devices attached` try restarting server:

```
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb devices
```

Comment: You're right, List of devices attached is empty. I tried the commands you posted above, but nothing changed. Also I got no outputs wehen killing the server, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it's O.K. that kill-server doesn't show any output. Do you have adb debugging enabled on your device? Can you try using it with different PC/Mac and/or try different device with your Mac?

Comment: Also this link could be useful: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4322/my-samsung-galaxy-3-gt-i5801-is-not-being-detected-in-my-pc-what-should-i-do

Comment: Yes, debugging is enabled on the device. As mentioned above all worked fine a few days ago... Sadly I don't have any other devices to test with. Let's see what that link brings up ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I recently discovered that I had switched a looking mini-usb **power** cable with a mini-usb **data** cable (the former was to recharge a bluetooth keyboard for a Nexus 7). Very, very frustrating, as the cables seem to be identical minus a data wire (as there doesn't seem to be a way to tell without switching cables (I.E., there's no indicator that yes, the phone is plugged in, but it isn't communicating (as opposed to being a driver problem))).

Answer (score 1):

Im using a samsung galaxy s3. I had the same problem. found out that the reason it read the phone in the first place was cause i was teathering. So i selected teather and that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I re-installed my Windows, I forgot to install the driver for my phone. The general usb driver was not enough - the one provided by the factory also needs to be installed. In my case I had to download PC Companion for my Xperia. Samsung has Kies.

Answer (score 0):

my celkon a85 android mobile also not detected by eclipse even after enabled usb debugging. there is no driver cd for such mobiles, windows says no wizard found to install. but 
"pdaNet for android" software helped to detect my phone.u can find that software [here](http://junefabrics.com/android/download.php) . just download it , and install with its guide, it will automatically install driver software for your android mobiles like celkon,micromax,etc., and this software helps your android phone to act as modem(like nokia pc suit ). u can connect interent in pc using your mobile network.

Answer (score 0):

I work on Linux and was able to get the message that too many files were open. I'm too stupid to know how to close them. So I rebooted my laptop and eclipse then recognized my phone again. I know there are admin terminal tools for closing files in Unix that would save you the reboot if you had to do this often.  In my case, it may be the webviews caching, which I adjusted.

Judging by the other suggestions, open files may be only one of the problems that causes this disruption.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Samsung Gio, android version 2.3.6, Linux Mint and Eclipse 3.8.0 . The link Maciek posted worked for me ( https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4322/my-samsung-galaxy-3-gt-i5801-is-not-being-detected-by-my-pc-what-should-i-d ). thx!