# Error connecting LG nexus 4 to Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, nexus-4

I am new to Android programming and have been unable to connected my phone to eclipse for debugging and running applications on the go since many days. I have enabled the USB debug mode etc, installed the Google USB drivers and followed all the steps mentioned on the official Google site
http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

As extra debugging steps for this problem, I tried the Android Debug Monitor tool (monitor.bat) but my phone didnt get recognised in that as well. Also I ensured the my project build SDK version was 19, which i believe is suitable for Android 4.4.4. I used a Moto G(4.4.2) and again I couldnt run apps on it from Eclipse.

But in five minutes by following the same steps I could get the debugging working with Samsung Galaxy duos(android 4.2.2, API 17)

Am I doing something wrong?

OS on PC - Windows 8

Comment: It's not clear what the error is. Without a specific description of what the problem is, it's not likely that anyone will be able to guess just based on a description of what you did and the general notion that it's not working. If you're getting an error message, explain when/where you get the message and post it verbatim.

Comment: Have you checked all the other similar questions on SO? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747482/why-wont-eclipse-detect-my-android-device -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371741/eclipse-wont-recognize-my-android-phone-cant-debug

Comment: @AdiInbar how do i get a specific error code or problem, I dont see any such thing on the screen. It just doesnt get connected. I have been trynig to fix this problem for the past 2 days, I have done an extensive search and only then posted my question here on SO.

Comment: A tidbit from my own experience in case it helps you: I have a 2012 Nexus 7 (1st gen). Once in awhile, when connecting it to my PC, Windows doesn't recognize it and, consequently, neither does Eclipse. I have not found a solution other than to power-down/power-up the tablet but that always works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download pda software from pdaorg.co this will surely help you. I was also running with same problem but after installing pda my problem has been sort out.

Comment: @BSKANIA do u have anu idea about xmpp?

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your phone's USB computer connection to Camera(PTP) mode. Worked on my side. Hope that helped.